# How to print contents of a text to console as objects

Tags: java, file, object, io

Let's say I have theese words in a text file

## Dictionary.txt

```
artificial
intelligence
abbreviation
hybrid
hysteresis
illuminance
identity
inaccuracy
impedance
impenetrable
imperfection
impossible
independent
```

How can I make each word a different object and print them on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use `Scanner.nextLine();` function.
Here is the following code which can help

also import the libraries

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Use following code:-

```
String []words = new String[1];
try{
   File file = new File("/path/to/Dictionary.txt");
Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
int i=0;
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
words[i]=scan.nextLine();
i++;
words = Arrays.copyOf(words,words.legnth+1); // Increasing legnth of array with 1
}
}
catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}
```

You must go and research on `Scanner` class

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It's a good idea to run code you're posting (JShell is good for this) as you have a typo (lenght for length) and also good to make the indentation correct and consistent (maybe use the formatter in an IDE).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple solution using `Files`:

```
package org.kodejava.io;

import java.net.URI;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ReadFileAsListDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReadFileAsListDemo demo = new ReadFileAsListDemo();
        demo.readFileAsList();
    }

    private void readFileAsList() {
        String fileName = "Dictionary.txt";

        try {
            URI uri = Objects.requireNonNull(this.getClass().getResource(fileName)).toURI();
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(uri),
                    Charset.defaultCharset());

            for (String line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Source: https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-read-all-lines-from-a-file/

This is another neat solution using buffered reader:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * BufferedReader and Scanner can be used to read
line by line from any File or
 * console in Java.
 * This Java program
demonstrate line by line reading using BufferedReader in Java
 *
 * @author Javin Paul
 */
public class BufferedReaderExample {  

    public static void main(String args[]) {
     
        //reading file line by line in Java using BufferedReader      
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
     
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("C:/sample.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
         
            System.out.println("Reading
File line by line using BufferedReader");
         
            String line = reader.readLine();
            while(line != null){
                System.out.println(line);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }          
         
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(BufferedReaderExample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
  }
```

Source: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/07/read-file-line-by-line-java-example-scanner.html#axzz7lrQcYlyy

Answer (score 0):

These are all good answers. The OP didn't state what release of Java they require, but in modern Java I'd just use:

```java
import java.nio.file.*;
public class x {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Files.lines(Path.of("/path/to/Dictionary.txt")).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```